# Can member functions create object of same class?

Tags: c++, class, object

Can a member function ("add") **create an object** ("k") of its class("distance") and **return** the same as shown in the code sample given below?

```
class distance
{
    int feet;
    float inches;

    public:

    distance(int feet, float inches)
    {
        this->feet=feet;
        this->inches=inches;
    }


    distance add(distance d)
    {
        distance k;
        k.feet=feet+10;
        k.inches=inches+8;
        return k;
    }
};

distance e(0,0.0);
```

Comment: Sure, but define a default constructor.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: I was so free to fix your typos. If these were the reasons for your problems, then just take it. Otherwise it's unclear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: as long as a class is copyable (as this is) or movable, you can return an instance from any function (including its own member functions). However, this

```
distance k;
```

won't work since there's no default constructor. Instead, use the available constructor:

```
return distance(feet+10, inches+8);
```

(You might also want to correct the name of the second constructor parameter; as it is, you're setting the `inches` member to its own uninitialised value. And `add` probably wants to do something with its parameter, not just add an arbitrary constant.)

Comment: Sry, I had made a mistake there. I have now changed the second constructor parameter. And how would I draw the default constructor for this class to use that 'distance k'? Thanks.

Comment: @h8pathak: If you really want a default constructor, then either write one like `distance() : feet(0), inches(0) {}`, or add default values to the existing constructor's parameters, `distance(int feet=0, float inches=0)`, so that it's usable as a default constructor. But think twice about doing that; it might be less error-prone to only allow construction with a specified value.

Comment: Wouldn't it work as I had passed the default values to the constructor when creating the object?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create an object of the same class in any of its methods